# what is wrong with my code it says array out of bounds index -1

Tags: java

```
try{
    String sql = "UPDATE Products SET ID=?, Category=?,Product=?,Price=?,InItem=?, OutItem=?, TimeOutItem=?, TotalStocks=?"
                      + "WHERE ID=? ";   
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(0, ID.getText());
    pst.setString(1, Category.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pst.setString(2, Product.getText());
    pst.setString(3, Price.getText());
    pst.setString(4, Quantity.getText());
    pst.setString(5, out.getText());
    pst.setString(6, date.getDateFormatString().toString());
    pst.setString(7, Stocks.getText());

    int rowsUpdated = pst.executeUpdate();
    if(rowsUpdated > 0){
        UpdateJTable();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Array index out of bounds -1. I don't know why there's still an error on my code please help.

Comment: this is the content of my products table. ID, Category, ProductName,Price, InItem,TimeInItem,OutItem,TimeOutItem,TotalStocks,Image.

Answer (score 2):

set the parameter starting from 1 not from 0

```
 pst.setString(1, ID.getText());
 pst.setString(2, Category.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Edit :Complete code

```
try{
    String sql = "UPDATE Products SET Category=?,Product=?,Price=?,InItem=?, OutItem=?, TimeOutItem=?, TotalStocks=?"
                      + " WHERE ID=? ";   
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, Category.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pst.setString(2, Product.getText());
    pst.setString(3, Price.getText());
    pst.setString(4, Quantity.getText());
    pst.setString(5, out.getText());
    pst.setString(6, date.getDateFormatString().toString());
    pst.setString(7, Stocks.getText());
    pst.setString(8, ID.getText());

    int rowsUpdated = pst.executeUpdate();
    if(rowsUpdated > 0){
        UpdateJTable();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: Ive done that and it says error on update statement.

Comment: @jayson what is the error ? add a space before `where` clause and you also have 9 parameters but you are passing only 8

Comment: int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                ID.setText(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
                Category.setSelectedItem(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
                Product.setText(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
                Price.setText(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
                Quantity.setText(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
                DateIn.setText(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5).toString()); etc.
 that is my JTable code when clicked

Comment: @jayson you have given me code not the error,give the stacktrace and also do what I said in comment above

Comment: i follow your instruction and it says Count field incorrect.

Comment: @singkahash Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'Pa_RaM006WHERE ID=Pa_RaM007'

Comment: @jayson add space before `where` clause and also update your question with your current code and stacktrace